# vsto repurpose font comboBox

Tags: vsto, powerpoint, office-interop

I'm trying to repurpose the built in font selector for my own objects in PowerPoint (vsto add-in). I repurpose regular commands (bold, italic etc.) successfully using the ribbon xml.

I have a test that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
 <ribbon>
   <tabs>
     <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="Test">
       <group id="MyGroup"
              label="My Group">
         <comboBox idMso="Font" label="ComboBox1" onChange="ChangeCallback"/>
       </group>
     </tab>
   </tabs>
 </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

If I have a regular is instead of the idMso this callback works fine:

```
ChangeCallback(Office.IRibbonControl control, string text)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Changed");
}
```

The callback stops working when I use idMso="Font", but the comboBox works and I can use it to select font like normal.

I have tried the following callback with no luck.

```
ChangeCallback(Office.IRibbonControl control, string text, ref bool cancelDefault)
{
     Debug.WriteLine("Changed");
}
```

When I repurpose commands I put it in the commands section of the xml instead of the ribbon, but having a comboBox element there is not allowed.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?